# Oracle Apex - All tabs showing at once instead of only active tab

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I created an apex page wherein i need to split my classic report of 50 columns into 5 tabs with 10 columns displaying in each.

1. So for each section, i created a static content region with template as tabs container.
2. Inside it as sub region i added the classic report.
3. Start New Row->No so that the Tab headers are all side by side.

After doing this for all 5 tabs when i run the page it shows all 5 tabs whereas i need to see the 1st tab by default and the rest only when i click on the respective tab name.

So only the tab on which i click needs to be active.

What am i implementing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a region display selector for this.

Create a region with template 'blank with no attributes'. This is typically placed in breadcrumb bar location, and can be configured to not 'show all'.

[image]

Now any content region with attribute 'region display selector' is shown tabulated.

Often you'll need to take care to ensure inline dialogs or other note regions don't have this attribute selected.